# Complex Power Series of $\cos(z-1)$

Tags: analysis

I am trying to revise for my analysis exam and am struggling to understand how to express $\cos(z-1)$ as the sum of a power series of the form:

$$\sum_{n\ge0} a_n(z-a)^n.$$

I think it's a pretty basic question I'm just unclear on the answer.

thanks.

Comment: Do you know something about Taylor series expansion? It's simply that.

Answer (score 1):

You know that

$$\cos(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} z^{2n}$$

since for instance

$$e^z=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$$

and

$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} z^{n}.$$

So now just do "$z\to z-1$".

Comment: i know its basic but i can't just sub $z=z-1$ in right

Comment: @ptsgeeg You can: just do "$y-1=z$" and here is your result.

Comment: so I can write: $$\cos(y-1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} (y-1)^{2n}$$ is the sum of the power series of $cos(y-1)$

Comment: @ptsgeeg Exactly! (since this series has an infinite rayon of convergence)

Comment: okay, this has been a great help. thank you!

Comment: @ptsgeeg Feel free to accept the answer if it suits you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use $\cos(z-1)=\cos((z-a)+(a-1))=\cos(z-a)\cos(a-1)-\sin(z-a)\sin(a-1)$,
so
$$
\cos(z-1)=\cos(a-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(z-a)^{2n}}{(2n!)}-
\sin(a-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(z-a)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(z-1)={\bf Re}(e^{i(z-1)})={\bf Re}\left(e^{-i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(iz)^n}{n!}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{{\bf Re}(e^{-i}i^nz^n)}{n!}$$